# RVM Error Installing ruby 2.3.0 on High Sierra

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, rvm

I updated my macOS to High Sierra, after that all pod commands like (pod install, pod update) stop working. After google search I advised to update your ruby from 2.0 to 2.3.0. But using rvm command am facing following Error.

```
 Zubair-mac-mini:~ sdsol$ rvm install 2.3.0

 Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
 No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
 Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more 
 information on binary rubies.
 Checking requirements for osx.
 Installing requirements for osx.
 Updating system.........Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions 
 here:
 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
 and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
 ..
 Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.3.0',
 please read /Users/sdsol/.rvm/log/1506680323_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log
 Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
 Zubair-mac-mini:~ sdsol$
```

Than I tried to update homebrew, but no luck again face another issue

```
 Zubair-mac-mini:~ sdsol$ brew update
 Error: /usr/local must be writable!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does it say in `/Users/sdsol/.rvm/log/1506680323_ruby-2.3.0/update_system.log`?   As for `/usr/local must be writable` that is the problem with Homebrew: you have to create a security risk and make /usr/local writable by "others" in order to use Homebrew.  See https://wincent.com/snippets/131

Comment: Is your `rvm` up to date? Try `rvm list known`. If `2.3` is not in the list, try updating: `rvm get stable`. Incidentally, you should always update to **the latest patch release** of a minor version; in this case you should update to `2.3.5`. And unless you have a good reason not to, just upgrade to the latest ruby version: `2.4.2`.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord, rvm `get stable` fix my problem.